# How do I keep a SQL connection throughout a webpage?

Tags: html, sql, web

Let's say I'm creating a basic page, said page's text varies depending on what's passed into it through a GET variable.

There's a header at the top of the page like so:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("stuff", "stuff", "stuff");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '{$_GET['url']}'");

//Now we have connected to the SQL database.
?>
```

Assuming I continued coding there, so that the header text varied depending on what was passed into the URL (however, this is irrelevant, it's the next part in which I want to question).

Now let's say that, further down the page, there is some more PHP code, but there is also more HTML code in between. If I wanted to access the database again in this second PHP snippet, do I have to reconnect to the database? Or is there a way I can make sure that the connection session stays open, even when it's a completely different `<?php ?>` area? How do i make it so that my SQL connection isn't dropped when I end the `<?php` tag?

Comment: it's stays the same unless you won't use `mysql_connect`

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Better you explain me why idea mysql drops your connection :)

Comment: Your example is vulnerable to SQL-injection, I wouldn't recommend you to use that code in production nor developement-enviroment.

Comment: _The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close()_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's address several issues at once :-)

1. The connection *will not be dropped* unless you explicitly do it yourself. It will be dropped when the script ends, of course. Even then, there are techniques of *persistent connection* and *connection pooling* that may help you avoid the overhead.
2. The `mysql_*` family of functions is **[deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)** and may soon cease working altogether. You'd be much better off by moving to e.g. [PDO functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), which are more powerful and safer too.
3. When you put a `_GET` parameter directly inside a SQL query (or other server code) without checking/validating, you expose yourself to the danger of that parameter containing some nasty surprise. The classic example, apart from [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/), is if you check that `$_GET['password']` corresponds to field `password`. If you just code it as

```
WHERE ... password = '$_GET[password]'
```

and someone places in that field the value

```
' OR ''=='
```

the SQL server will see

```
WHERE ... password = '' OR ''==''
```

and since '' *is* indeed equal to '', that query will return **true** -- and the user will be logged in without knowing the password. Such "[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)", if possible at all, can often be tuned to the point of allowing an attacker to be recognized as the site's administrator, with all that entails. And that's why you **don't** want to use client-side parameters "as is". PDO's prepared statements can help there, too.

Comment: Just a note, I'm aware about the errors I made in that part, but that's not what I'm asking about. just Letting you know :)

Comment: OK, just to be sure. Then only #1 applies :-)

Comment: By "when the script ends" do you mean when everything is done, or when I add the ?> tag? because that's what I was asking, how do I keep the session accross scripts?

Comment: @ShaunWild "When the script ends" is when the file ends. There can be multiple `<?php>` in a file.

Comment: When either the *last* `?>` tag closes, or you explicitly call `exit()/die()`. As for the session, you use `session_*` functions and the `$_SESSION` superglobal; this persists data between distinct calls to separate scripts (or to the same script). DB connection **will not survive** in these circumstances, and you will have to open it again. But with proper management (see answer, #1), these subsequent "opens" will not cost so much.

Answer (score 1):

From:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

> Note:
> The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close().

## edit

sorry, wrong language :)